# React cannot pass props to createElement, Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

Hi i am trying to pass simple string as prop , but react tell me its  anobject.
This is my code,

```
import RuleForm from './ruleForm'
```

my state,

```
child: RuleForm,
children:[]
```

and in my componentDidMount:

```
this.setState({   children:this.state.children.concat(React.createElement(this.state.child),
                    {color: 'blue', shadowSize: 2},
                    'Click Me'
                )
            })
```

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be storing React components in your state. That's a realy bad practice! In fact, according to the code that you have just provided, children could very well be just a number. I guess you are mutating that child state at some point, but even then you definitely shouldn't store components. Anyway, you have to show us the way you are rendering that state in your render method if you want us to help you. Try to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Comment: " you shouldn't be storing " thanks its the first time i am doing it , thought it was strange too, was following a tutorial.